# Roboframework exit on success of a specific test

Tags: robotframework

I am looking for a way to make robotframework exits the execution of a test suite if a specific test passes. It is the exact contrary of what --exitonfailuredoes so I want to know if there is a way to do this with robot framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to and including robot framework 3.1 there is no good way to skip tests once a test run has started, except to call [Fatal Error][1]. Being able to skip tests has been a feature that people have wanted for many years now.

At the time that I write this, it does not appear that this feature will be added in version 3.2.